# Is there a way to log all urls in chrome's incognito mode for android?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, logging, incognito-mode

I'm writing a parental controll app and want to make sure everything get's monitored.

As incognito mode doesn't record any history I can't get it with :

```
     String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED,
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE,
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS,
                                 Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID };

    Uri uriCustom = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; 
    Cursor mCur = this.getContentResolver().query(uriCustom, proj, sel, null, null);

    url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
```

Comment: Is it possible to disable incognito-mode?

Comment: If there is way, I'd consider that a bug in Chrome ;)

Comment: @GregorRaýman, I can actually get it in C# for chrome's desktop browser so i guess there's a bug ?